# Переопределение типа "class" C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, cmake, стандарт

Есть главный файл main.cpp и main.h. В main.cpp подключается заголовок Engine.h. Компилятор выдает ошибку переопределения типа "class"

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Game game = Game("init");
    cout << game.getState() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
```

**Engine.cpp**

```
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game(string state)
    {
        this->state = state;
    }

    string getState()
    {
        return this->state;
    }
private:
    string state;
};
```

**Engine.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game(string state);
    string getState();
private:
    string state;
};
```

Собирается через CMake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим ваш `Engine.cpp`:

```
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
```

Т.е., когда будет включен ваш `Engine.h`, получится что-то вроде

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
    Game(string state);
    string getState();
private:
    string state;
};

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:

...
```

Т.е. класс `Game` у вас определяется в этой единице трансляции дважды.

Дальше пояснять не нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Повторно определять класс `class Game {` нельзя.
А в `Engine.cpp` можно сделать полное определение методов которые вы предварительно объявили так :

```cpp
# include "Engine.h"

Game :: Game(string state)
{
  this->state = state;
}

string Game :: getState()
{
  return this->state;
}
```

где `Game ::` означает область *(класс)*, для кого эта функция определяется.